# GeolocationAccessStatus change event doesn't raise

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm developing a windows mobile app using Windows 10 SDK (build 10586) and I need to subscribe to StatusChanged event of Geolocator.

The problem is, when I switch off geolocation using Settings > Location menu, my OnStatusChanged method is not called.

```
    public async Task StartTracking()
    {
        // Request permission to access location
        var accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();

        switch (accessStatus)
        {
            case GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed:
                _geolocator = new Geolocator
                {
                    ReportInterval = 2000,
                    MovementThreshold = 10d,
                    DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 10,
                    DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High
                };
                _geolocator.PositionChanged += OnPositionChanged;
                _geolocator.StatusChanged += OnStatusChanged;
                break;

            case GeolocationAccessStatus.Denied:
                Messenger.Default.Send(new GeolocationDeniedAccessMessage(true));
                break;

            case GeolocationAccessStatus.Unspecified:
                Messenger.Default.Send(new GeolocationDeniedAccessMessage(true));
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnStatusChanged(Geolocator sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Status)
        {
            case PositionStatus.Ready:
                Messenger.Default.Send(new GeolocationAvailabilityMessage(true));
                Messenger.Default.Send(new GeolocationDeniedAccessMessage(false));
                break;

            case PositionStatus.Initializing:
                break;

            case PositionStatus.NoData:
                Messenger.Default.Send(new GeolocationAvailabilityMessage(false));
                break;

            case PositionStatus.Disabled:
                Messenger.Default.Send(new GeolocationDeniedAccessMessage(true));
                break;

            case PositionStatus.NotInitialized:
                break;

            case PositionStatus.NotAvailable:
                Messenger.Default.Send(new GeolocationAvailabilityMessage(false));
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is happening after you switch the geolocation off in the Settings menu?

Comment: Absolutely nothing! This is *really* strange... None of my events are raised

Comment: Well, the solution was that simple: instanciate the geolocator not in the GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed part, but in the constructor, so that event are tracked in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The problem seems to be the registration for the `EventHandler`. If the Location is disabled once `StartTracking()` is called the `GeolocationAccessStatus` will be "denied" so the `EventHandler` never gets registered and `OnStatusChanged` will not be called once the user turns on location tracking in the settings.
Try moving the initialization of the `Geolocator` out of the `GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed` case

---

Make sure that you have selected `Location` in the capabilities tab of your manifest `package.appxmanifest`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've already enabled Location capability

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. If this was the problem, he would have other problems much sooner.

Comment: Not necessarily since there is no exception thrown if you want to request access to the user location and the "Location" capability is not set.
The main mistake with this question is the registration of the event handler. Check out my updated answer

Comment: That was exactly my issue ! (I mean, the updated answer). Of course, I had to instanciate my geolocator at the very begining, and not in the GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed part.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused if location services are not enabled in Windows 10.

From the Desktop, go to All Settings -> Privacy -> Location and ensure Location is set to ON.